# How to pass arguments to ScalaTest runner in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest with the ScalaTest Eclipse plugin in ScalaIde in Eclipse, and I'd like to use tags for my tests.  In the docs for ScalaTest tags (http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.Tag), it says that after you've set up the tags:

"When you run ScalaTest and want to either include or exclude DbTests (for example), you'd give the fully qualified name of the tag annotation (which is also the name passed to the corresponding Tag constructor) to Runner"

But I'm not invoking the runner from the command line or via the Scala "run" method - I'm using the @RunWith annotation ie - "@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])".  What's the best way to pass tags to the runner?

Answer (score 0):

Bill Venners (the author of ScalaTest) answered my question on the ScalaTest Google Group, so I want to pass that answer along in case anyone else is interested.

In a nutshell, no, the @RunWith annotation above is using the Junit runner, and ScalaTest currently doesn't pass the tags along to JUnit.  If I want to use tags, I'll have to use a different runner.